# Как сделать форматирование сразу всех столбцов в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, форматирование

У меня есть несколько столбцов, допустим
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу посчитать описательные статистики при помощи describe, но мне нужно, чтобы результат выводился не в таком виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, а с округлением до 2 знаков после запятой.

Как сделать это для одного столбца понятно:

```
df['Знания'].describe(include = 'all').apply("{0:.2f}".format)
```

Но можно ли это сделать сразу для всех столбцов? Чтобы выводился результат для всех столбцов уже отформатированный.

Заранее спаисбо

Comment: Прошу прощения, питон

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста в заголовке вопроса и в тегах в чем (какое ПО, какой язык) вы это делаете, тогда вам помогут быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, тогда всё, что будет выводиться `Pandas` на экран, будет в этом формате:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

Вообще почитайте варианты по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns), там много что предлагают.

Хотя в вашем случае возможно достаточно будет сделать так:

```
df.describe(include = 'all').applymap("{:.2f}".format)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Когда вывожу на экран помогает. Но если сохраняю переменную в документ сразу, то остается по-прежнему: без форматирования. Попробую поискать по Вашей ссылке!

Comment: Так это формат отображения, в памяти данные хранятся без изменения. Если надо потом в файл сохранить, например через `to_csv`, так у этой функции тоже есть параметр `float_format`

Comment: А если вам надо сами данные округлить, то есть функция `round(decimals=2)` для `Pandas Series`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Замечательно помогли и еще кучу нового рассказали! (щелкаю, что ответ полезен, но у меня маленький рейтинг и публично не учитывается, к сожалению)

Comment: Галку поставьте, если ответ решил проблему вашу